# List Directories like wamp page in PHP

Tags: php, html, directory

I am looking for a way to list the names of every folder in a directory and their path in PHP

Thank you

Comment: Google "list the names of every folder in a directory and their path in PHP".

Comment: are you probably referring to the index.html?

Answer (score 2):

What you are referring to is not a page from WAMPP, it is a default setting to show files and folders on any (if not most) web servers... This is usually switched off by the web server config, or [.htaccess files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess)

You are looking for some PHP code to do a similar thing, the following PHP functions are what you will need to look into, read the pages and view the examples to understand how to use them... Do not ignore "Warning" or "Important" messages on these pages from php.net:

- [opendir](http://php.net/opendir) - Creates a handle to a directory for reading
- [readdir](http://php.net/readdir) - Reads files/folders inside a dir
- [rmdir](http://php.net/rmdir) - Deletes a folder (must be empty)
- [mkdir](http://php.net/mkdir) - Creates a folder

Here is an example:

```
<?php
$folder = "myfolder";
if ($dhandle = opendir($folder)) {

  while ($file = readdir($dhandle)) {

  // Ignore . and ..
  if ($file<>'.' && $file<>'..')

  // if it's a folder, echo [F]

  if (is_dir("$folder/$file")) echo "[F] $file<br>"; else
  echo "$file<br>";

  }
closedir($dhandle);
}
?>
```

**Important**
Remember that on a linux OS, your Apache/PHP must have access to the folder in question before it can write/delete files and folders... Read up on [chmod](http://php.net/chmod), [chown](http://php.net/chown) and [chgrp](http://php.net/chgrp)

Answer (score 1):

use the following function to get the path of the files/folders

```
<?php 

function getDirectory( $path = '.', $level = 0 ){ 

    $ignore = array( 'cgi-bin', '.', '..' ); 
    // Directories to ignore when listing output. Many hosts 
    // will deny PHP access to the cgi-bin. 

    $dh = @opendir( $path ); 
    // Open the directory to the handle $dh 

    while( false !== ( $file = readdir( $dh ) ) ){ 
    // Loop through the directory 

        if( !in_array( $file, $ignore ) ){ 
        // Check that this file is not to be ignored 

            $spaces = str_repeat( '&nbsp;', ( $level * 4 ) ); 
            // Just to add spacing to the list, to better 
            // show the directory tree. 

            if( is_dir( "$path/$file" ) ){ 
            // Its a directory, so we need to keep reading down... 

                echo "<strong>$spaces $file</strong><br />"; 
                getDirectory( "$path/$file", ($level+1) ); 
                // Re-call this same function but on a new directory. 
                // this is what makes function recursive. 

            } else { 

                echo "$spaces $file<br />"; 
                // Just print out the filename 

            } 

        } 

    } 

    closedir( $dh ); 
    // Close the directory handle 

} 
getDirectory( "." ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an simple solution to this problem :(if you are using linux only )

you want list the names of every folder in a directory and their path in PHP .

you can use

```
 find
```

command in conjuction with PHP's

```
exec();
```

function

the following snippet shows this

```
<?php
    $startdir = "Some Directory" ; // the start directory whose sub directories along with path is needed
    exec("find  " . $startdir . " -type d " , $directories); // executes the command and stores the result in array $directory line by line
    while(list($index,$dir) = each($directories) ) {
        echo $dir."<br/>"; //lists directories one by one 
    }
?>
```

foot notes:

command ,

```
find dirname -type d
```

lists all the directories and subdirectories under folder startdir

Answer (score 0):

This is a php code save this as index.php and put it in your web root directory.

```
<?php
$pngFolder = <<< EOFILE
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
EOFILE;

if (isset($_GET['img']))
{
       header("Content-type: image/png");
        echo base64_decode($pngFolder);
        exit();
}


$projectsListIgnore = array ('.','..'); 
$handle=opendir(".");
$projectContents = '';
while ($file = readdir($handle)) 
{
    if (is_dir($file) && !in_array($file,$projectsListIgnore)) 
    {       
        $projectContents .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
    }
}
closedir($handle);

?>
<ul class="projects">
<?php $projectContents ?>
</ul>
```